# MQ client key repository questions

Tags: ibm-mq

I am currently developing an MQ application client-side, that is meant to establish connection between a machine and a distant server, and I need to implement SSL connection between them. The server was already configured with a given certificate that I was sent. The problem is : I can't understand what exactly needs to be done with the key repository part.

It looks like the MQCONNX call is expecting not only a certificate name (label), but also a key database (kdb) file, which I don't have. Thus I have several question, because it seems like I don't understand every aspect of the certificate part:

- How can I get the kdb file linked to the certificate? Is it supposed to be generated by the person who made the certificate?
- Where is it supposed to be stored? Can I use any folder/name?

A little background : I am working on Windows and developping with C MQ libraries. Before the SSL requirement was added, everything was working properly : I could connect to the queue manager and post messages into a given queue. Now I get error 2381 MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR, which will probably be gone after this key repository part is solved.

Thanks a lot for all your answers.

Cheers,

Comment: If you have MQ samples installed, there is amqsssl.c sample that describes creating secure connections to queue manager.

Comment: There is an IBM MQ TLS tutorial on IBM Developer here > https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-secure-msgs-tls/ < does this help?

Comment: "with a given certificate that I was sent." What exactly where you sent? Was it a BASE64 encode public key or some form of a private key?

Comment: Hey thanks for replying! The sample did help me for programming but now I need to fill the blanks. I'll try to read the tutorial above when I get back to work. I have a .crt certificate. And that's it. I think I need to ask the publisher of the certificate to also give me a .kdb key database linked to the certificate, am I right?

Comment: You can use runmqakm to create a kdb and then to import the crt into the kdb.

Comment: Ha it was that simple yet I couldn't find the proper information. With that command I could create the kdb file and set everythin up. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think between them the comments to your question provide the answer. In essence your client application (or the underlying MQ C layer) needs to trust the certificate that the server is sending.

If the certificate you have was signed by a trusted certificate authority,
then your app needs to be told to trust the public key of the certificate authority. If it is self-signed, then your app needs to be told to trust the public certificate.

Either way, you will need a keystore. The keystore holds all the public keys and public keys of certificate signers that you trust.

To create the keystore, follow the "Create a client keystore" section of https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-secure-msgs-tls/

These steps will create a keystore containing the certificate that you have been sent.

You then tell your application where to find the trusted keys keystore by setting the environment variable `MQSSLKEYR`

```
// MQSSLKEYR is need so that the MQ client knows what keystore to use..
// note it is the full path, including the base file name but not the .kdb extension
// my keystore file is user.kdb in the C:\tmp subdirectory..
set MQSSLKEYR=C:\tmp\user
```

see - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=wsulw-specifying-key-repository-location-mq-mqi-client-unix-linux-windows

and

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-do-i-configure-mq-client-c-based-application-amqsputc-amqsgetc-connect-mq-server-ssl